# How to change NodeJS Request Stream response

Tags: node.js, express

I'm somewhat new to NodeJS, and current I used Express and Request ( https://github.com/request/request ) to forward my app request to REST api server, current my code shown below:

```
app.use('/rest/*', function(req, res) {
    req.pipe(request('http://ipaddress/api')).pipe(res);
});
```

this code works when the REST API server is OK, but if the rest api server goes down, my nodejs app also goes down, because request stream will fail and the error is not caught by my app.
I checked the Request github page, it provides one way to handle the stream error, like

```
app.use('/rest/*', function(req, res) {
    req.pipe(request('http://ipaddress/api').on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })).pipe(res);
});
```

this can only log the error and prevent my NodeJS app crashing, but I want to change the response when error occurred so that the changed response can be piped to final one, for example, what I want to do in pseudocode:

```
app.use('/rest/*', function(req, res) {
    req.pipe(request('http://ipaddress/api').on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        // what I want to do in pseudocode
        response.statusCode = 500;
        response.json = {
            reason: err.errno 
        };
    })).pipe(res);
});
```

Are there any ways to solve my problems?  Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: That might not be possible with only a single request, since the headers have already been sent by the time the error is likely to occur. Instead what you should do is make a HEAD request to the api server from the node server to check if it's online, then if that works out go ahead and pipe the API request to the client. Otherwise, you can send whatever response you want to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but could you pass the error back to middleware to handle the reponse?

```
app.use('/rest/*', function(req, res, next) {
    req.pipe(request('http://ipaddress/api').on('error', function(err) {
        return next(err)
    })).pipe(res);
});
```

Handled like so

```
// Exception handling
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(error));    
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!  My only question is next() method used in Exception handling method, I have tried to remove the next() method call, it also works.  Could you tell me why next() used here?

Comment: Only really used in the exception handling if you have further (middleware) actions to perform - you may have a logging function for example